# Neural A* enviroment installation

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, python-venv

i have ubuntu 23.04 i'm trying to install e and execute neural A* from https://github.com/omron-sinicx/neural-astar?tab=readme-ov-file by following the instructions. I have python 3.12.1 and after the command

```
pip install .[dev]
```

this is the error it gives me:

```
Processing /home/sam/Desktop/Tesi/neuralAstar/neural-astar
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of neural-astar[dev] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.12.1 (from neural-astar[dev]) (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.1

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

I tried to update pip and i tried by installing torch 1.12.1 with pip install torch==1.12.1+cpu torchvision==0.13.1+cpu torchaudio==0.12.1 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu and it doesn work. I tried also with conda (
conda install pytorch==1.12.1 torchvision==0.13.1 torchaudio==0.12.1 cpuonly -c pytorch
) but this is the output:

```
Channels:
 - pytorch
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides cudatoolkit >=11.6,<11.7 needed by torchvision-0.13.1-py310_cu116

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.12.* , which can be installed;
└─ torchvision 0.13.1  is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ torchvision 0.13.1 would require
   │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ torchvision 0.13.1 would require
   │  └─ cudatoolkit >=11.6,<11.7 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   ├─ torchvision 0.13.1 would require
   │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ torchvision 0.13.1 would require
   │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   └─ torchvision 0.13.1 would require
      └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.12.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

EDIT:

By editing the files pyproject.toml and src/neural_astar.egg_info/PKG_info and requires.txt with the update version of torch and torchvision i meanaged to install by pip install .[dev], but still i cant run the example and the scripts

EDIT2: By installing python 3.8 it works